# Retrieving in R the dropdown list values of a cell of an Excel file

Tags: r, excel

Hello from Paris (France),
I am quite new in R programming.
My question is: can I retrieve and update in a R DataFrame the values of a dropdown list of an EXCEL 2010 file cell.
I browsed the net about this topic, but nothing was relevant as a solution.
Thank you in advance for your help and your time :)

Comment: Drop-down values in Excel are often set via a cell range mapped in the Data Validation menu, if this is the case, you'd be better off reading that cell range directly.

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.